# Zoom in on hover image and keep same size

Tags: html, css, hover, zooming

I am trying to have the hover zoom feature for my website, however, I have seen other examples and my code seems to be the same, however the dimensions of the image doesn't stay the same. Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
.imgBox {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out
}
```

```css
  .imgBox {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out
  }
  .imgBox:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
```

```html
<div class="large-3 medium-6 small-12 columns">
  <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  <img class="imgBox" src="http://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/300x200.png" />
  <p>Paragraph here</p>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2gh0juvx/)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/2gh0juvx/1/

Comment: yes thank you. it works

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to scale the image which is fine but to restrict what is actually seen requires that the image be scaled *within a container*.

Then when the image is scaled, the container will hide anything that would normally "spill out" if you didn't hide the overlflow.

So, like this:

```css
.imgBox { /* now a container for the image */
    display: inline-block; /* shrink wrap to image */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide the excess */
  }
  .imgBox img {
    display: block; /* no whitespace */
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .imgBox:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
```

```html
<div class="large-3 medium-6 small-12 columns">
  <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  <div class="imgBox">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-300-200-9.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Paulie is right for sure but there also one more way you can use `background-image` instead of `img` tag

```css
  .imageWrapper{
    background-image:url("http://techmadeplain.com/img/2014/300x200.png");
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-size:100%;  
    background-position: center center;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .imageWrapper:hover{
    background-size:130%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="large-3 medium-6 small-12 columns">
  <h2>Heading 1</h2>
  <div class='imageWrapper'> 
  </div>  
  <p>Paragraph here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I shall forever be in your debt